# Consulta para ver que cumpla con varios requisitos de una misma tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola espero me puedan ayudar tengo 2 tablas.

Tabla productos
Tabla Atribuos

Tabla productos

**id nombre**

1  Producto A

2 Producto B

Y tengo otra tabla Atributos

Tabla atributos

**id id_producto atributo**

1 Producto A  Atributo A

2 Producto A  Atributo B

3 Producto B  Atributo A

4 Producto B  Atributo C

El problema que tengo es en el sql que debo traer un producto que cumpla que debe tener ambos atributos

intente haciendolo con un AND

`Select * from producto inner join atributo on atributo.id_producto=producto.id where atributo.nombre='Atributo A' and atributo.nombre='Atributo B'`

Y no me trae ninguno

intente haciendolo con un OR

`Select * from producto inner join atributo on atributo.id_producto=producto.id where atributo.nombre='Atributo A' or atributo.nombre='Atributo B'`

pero me trae registros que con tal que cumplan 1 solo atributo ya los acepta,... necesito ver si hay una forma de que me traiga registros que solo me traiga cuando **CUMPLAN CON TODOS LOS ATRIBUTOs**

Espero me puedan ayudar gracias

Comment: yun count del lado de atributos?

Answer (score 1):

Si es como dices, en la tabla `atributo` tienes los datos así:

```
id    id_producto     atributo
------------------------------------
1     Producto A      Atributo A
2     Producto A      Atributo B
3     Producto B      Atributo A
4     Producto B      Atributo C
```

Si observas, lo que haría la relación con `producto` sería la columna `nombre`, porque en `id_producto` de la tabla `atributo` tú estás poniendo los valores para `nombre`, no para `id`. Cabe decir que esto, si está así, es un diseño incorrecto y que tu tabla debería verse así:

```
id    id_producto     atributo
------------------------------------
1     1               Atributo A
2     1               Atributo B
3     2               Atributo A
4     2               Atributo C
```

Es más, si `Atributo A` se repite, como parece ser en las filas `1` y `3`, puede que haga falta una tabla asociativa que relacione `producto_atributo`, pero esa es otra historia.

Por otra parte, y siguiendo el problema que nos ocupa, puedes lograr lo que quieres con un filtro del tipo `OR` y usando `LEFT JOIN`, algo así:

### Caso A (no recomendado)

Si se usa `nombre` para la relación, lo cual no es para nada recomendado.

```
SELECT * 
FROM producto AS p
    LEFT JOIN atributo AS a
    ON a.id_producto=p.nombre 
WHERE a.nombre='Atributo A' OR a.nombre='Atributo B';
```

O bien puedes usar `IN` de este modo:

```
SELECT * 
FROM producto AS p
    LEFT JOIN atributo AS a
    ON a.id_producto=p.nombre 
WHERE a.nombre IN('Atributo A','Atributo B');
```

---

### Caso B (recomendado)

Si se usa `id` para la relación:

```
SELECT * 
FROM producto AS p
    LEFT JOIN atributo AS a
    ON a.id_producto=p.id 
WHERE a.nombre IN('Atributo A','Atributo B');
```

Otra cosa que no queda clara en tu pregunta es si quieres agrupar, puedes que necesites algo así o parecido:

```
-- Resultados agrupados

SELECT 
    p.id AS id_producto,
    GROUP_CONCAT(a.nombre) AS atributos
FROM producto AS p
    LEFT JOIN atributo AS a
    ON a.id_producto=p.id 
WHERE a.nombre IN('Atributo A','Atributo B')
GROUP BY p.id
;
```

Sea como sea, te dejo dos fiddles con cada caso, aplica lo que mejor te convenga.

#### Fiddle para Caso A (no recomendado)

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
/*
    Caso A: no recomendado
*/

CREATE TABLE producto (
  id INT,
  nombre VARCHAR(150)
);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES 
    (1, 'Producto A'),
    (2, 'Producto B')
;

CREATE TABLE atributo (
  id INT,
  id_producto VARCHAR(150),
  nombre VARCHAR(150)
);
INSERT INTO atributo VALUES 
    (1, 'Producto A', 'Atributo A'),
    (2, 'Producto A', 'Atributo B'),
    (3, 'Producto B', 'Atributo A'),
    (4, 'Producto B', 'Atributo C')    
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * 
FROM producto AS p
    LEFT JOIN atributo AS a
    ON a.id_producto=p.nombre 
WHERE a.nombre='Atributo A' OR a.nombre='Atributo B';
```

| id | nombre | id | id_producto | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Producto A | 1 | Producto A | Atributo A |
| 1 | Producto A | 2 | Producto A | Atributo B |
| 2 | Producto B | 3 | Producto B | Atributo A |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT * 
FROM producto AS p
    LEFT JOIN atributo AS a
    ON a.id_producto=p.nombre 
WHERE a.nombre IN('Atributo A','Atributo B')
;
```

| id | nombre | id | id_producto | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Producto A | 1 | Producto A | Atributo A |
| 1 | Producto A | 2 | Producto A | Atributo B |
| 2 | Producto B | 3 | Producto B | Atributo A |

---

**Query #3**

```
SELECT 
    p.id AS id_producto,
    GROUP_CONCAT(a.nombre) AS atributos
FROM producto AS p
    LEFT JOIN atributo AS a
    ON a.id_producto=p.nombre 
WHERE a.nombre IN('Atributo A','Atributo B')
GROUP BY p.id
;
```

| id_producto | atributos |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Atributo A,Atributo B |
| 2 | Atributo A |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kk5mYP3BByW3i7ThqRWZwD/0)

---

#### Fiddle para Caso B (recomendado)

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
/*
    Caso B: recomendado
*/

CREATE TABLE producto (
  id INT,
  nombre VARCHAR(150)
);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES 
    (1, 'Producto A'),
    (2, 'Producto B')
;

CREATE TABLE atributo (
  id INT,
  id_producto INT,
  nombre VARCHAR(150)
);
INSERT INTO atributo VALUES 
    (1, 1, 'Atributo A'),
    (2, 1, 'Atributo B'),
    (3, 2, 'Atributo A'),
    (4, 2, 'Atributo C')
    
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * 
FROM producto AS p
    LEFT JOIN atributo AS a
    ON a.id_producto=p.id 
WHERE a.nombre IN('Atributo A','Atributo B');
```

| id | nombre | id | id_producto | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Producto A | 1 | 1 | Atributo A |
| 1 | Producto A | 2 | 1 | Atributo B |
| 2 | Producto B | 3 | 2 | Atributo A |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT 
    p.id AS id_producto,
    GROUP_CONCAT(a.nombre) AS atributos
FROM producto AS p
    LEFT JOIN atributo AS a
    ON a.id_producto=p.id 
WHERE a.nombre IN('Atributo A','Atributo B')
GROUP BY p.id
;
```

| id_producto | atributos |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Atributo B,Atributo A |
| 2 | Atributo A |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/csC9rhsatc8EDoU2LXTY6m/0)

Comment: Disculpa que no me expresse bien no es con el nombre de producto es con los id la asociacion solo puse el nombre para ser mas claro, y en este caso no me serviria el OR por que debe cumplir ambos si o si y al ser OR con cual que cumpla 1 ya me lo trae.. Tambien he intentado con la clausila IN pero la respuesta es la misma que el IN

Comment: @WilsonFreddyAndiaAlborta ¿podrías poner un ejemplo del resultado esperado?